# how to inherited dunder __bool__ to multi class

Tags: python-3.x, class, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I modify the code so I also to use `checkbox` function to check page.fName, page.lName or page.email true or false currectly.

```
class Text(object):

    def check(self):
        if 'path' in self.locator:
            return False
        elif 'email' in self.locator:
            return True

    __bool__ = check


class namebox(Text):

    def __init__(self):
        self.locator = 'locator path'

    def is_enaled(self):
        return self.check()


class emailbox(Text):
    def __init__(self):
        self.locator = 'email'


class page_module():
    fName = namebox()
    lName = namebox()
    email = emailbox()

    def checkbox(self, instance):
        return bool(instance)

    print(fName.is_enaled())
    print('fName is using is_enabled function=>{}'.format(fName.is_enaled()))
    print('fName is using check function=>{}'.format(fName.check()))
    print('fName is using boolean function=>{}'.format(bool(fName)))
    print('email is using check function=>{}'.format(email.check()))
    print('email is using boolean function=>{}'.format(bool(email)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    page = page_module()
    print('check instance bool =>{}'.format(page.checkbox(page.fName))) #expect false, return false
    page.fName = 'first name'
    print('fName is =>{}'.format(page.fName))
    print('check instance bool =>{}'.format(page.checkbox(page.fName))) #expect false, return true
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem with an [mcve]?

Comment: modify the question, my question is if it possible i can just check if fName, lName or emails locator contains path or email one I assign string to it

Answer (score 0):

When you do `page.fName = 'first name'` in your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, you're shadowing the class variable `fName` with an instance variable that is bound to a string. Since the string is not empty, `bool(page.fName)` is `True`.

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're trying to do here. Perhaps you want `fName` and the other class variables to be [descriptors](https://www.smallsurething.com/python-descriptors-made-simple/), so that they can intercept assignments and value lookups made on instances of `page_module`?

Comment: The `Text` class you've shown is *not* a descriptor. That requres at least one of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__` (and usually both of the first two or all three). If you're created those methods but left them out of the question, then we can't tell what you're doing and you need to make a [mcve]. If you're asking for help implementing them, you need to be clearer on what behavior you're expecting (it's going to be hard to get a different boolean result from a descriptor than you get from its value).

Comment: thank you, i get the descriptions working. but my question turns into what if I have more than 3 function that would like to use? anyway to match __get__ or different operations?

Comment: You generally can't call extra methods on a descriptor, since when you look it up on an instance, you get the return value of the `__get__` method. Now, that returned value could be some kind of wrapper around another object (with extra methods), but I'm not really sure if that can do what you want.